# Adjust font size in percent in Safari, like Safari Mobile

Tags: javascript, macos, css, safari, webkit

I am working on a Safari extension.

In iOS, with CSS3, we can adjust the font size in percentage with `webkitTextSizeAdjust`.

For example :

```
document.querySelector("h1").style.webkitTextSizeAdjust = '200%';
```

But it doesn't work with Safari for OS X.

How can I reproduce the same on Safari desktop ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to change the font size you can do this:

```
document.querySelector("h1").style.fontSize = '200%';
```